# Use official logo and images on my site

Tags: promotions

Can I use official logo and images on my foreign site about Craft CMS? Are there any promo materials in good quality?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I believe this is perfectly acceptable. As long as you are not pretending to *be* Craft CMS or Pixel & Tonic, then you shouldn’t run into any legal issues.

They even made their brand assets available for use...

> https://craftcms.com/brand-assets

If you still have questions, send an email to support@craftcms.com.